# How to change the width of tasks in taskbar?

Tags: ubuntu, kde, kubuntu

[image]
I am using Kubuntu. I am interested in changing the width of tasks in task manager but didn't see it in 'Task Manager Settings', Is there a config file for this or how to do it anyway?

Comment: I've never seen an option like that. The size is dynamic. It starts at some default and gets smaller as more tasks are added. By default, multiple tasks from the same program are stacked. This stacking can be disabled. You can control which tasks get displayed by checking Only from this desktop. I don't know what Only from this screen does - maybe it's for multi-monitor displays. My experience is that there's never enough room for everything.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you can try asking on the official KDE Workspace community forum:  forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=66